# Office Addin Excel Not Saving

Tags: javascript, excel, office-addins

I am using office.js to interact with Excel using my office-addin. Microsoft documentation says we can save Excel using below code, but it keeps giving me this console error

```
TypeError: context.workbook.save is not a function
```

Link to Microsoft doc -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.workbook?view=excel-js-preview#save_saveBehavior_

```
await Excel.run(async (context) => {
                    if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('ExcelAPI', '1.11')) {
                        context.workbook.save(Excel.SaveBehavior.save);
                        console.log('supported');
                    } else {
                        console.log('not supported');
                    }
                })
```

I tried a lot but can't get out of this error. I was just wondering if I am doing something wrong or Microsoft documentation is incorrect. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

ExcelAPI', '1.5' start supporting save excel, callback function try to end with

```
return context.sync()
```